# How to remove html tags from an Html string using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an HTML string containing names:

```
<div class=\"ExternalClassBE95E28C1751447DB985774141C7FE9C\"><p>Tina Schmelz<br></p><p>Sascha Balke<br></p></div>
```

And, I would like to remove all html tags and put '&' between names but not at the end of last one like:

```
Not desired: Tina Schmelz & Sascha Balke &
Desired:     Tina Schmelz & Sascha Balke
```

I used regex and string replace property.

I could do it by using replace all for `<br>` tags with ' & ' and then removed all html tags by using this codes:

```js
let mytext = '<div class=\"ExternalClassBE95E28C1751447DB985774141C7FE9C\"><p>Tina Schmelz<br></p><p>Sascha Balke<br></p></div>';
mytext = mytext.replaceAll(/<br>/gi, ' & ');
mytext = mytext.replaceAll(/<.*?>/gi, ''); 

console.log(mytext)
```

My question: how can I remove last ' & '? Or, does anyone knows better RegEx for it to complete everything in one line? :)

Comment: Do your names always come in p tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.replace(/<br>(?=(?:\s*<[^>]*>)*$)|(<br>)|<[^>]*>/gi, (x,y) => y ? ' & ' : '')
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = '<div class="ExternalClassBE95E28C1751447DB985774141C7FE9C"><p>Tina Schmelz<br></p><p>Sascha Balke<br></p></div>';
const regex = /<br>(?=(?:\s*<[^>]*>)*$)|(<br>)|<[^>]*>/gi;
console.log(
  text.replace(regex, (x,y) => y ? ' & ' : '')
);
```

*Details*:

- `<br>(?=(?:\s*<[^>]*>)*$)` - a `<br>` that is followed with zero or more occurrences of zero or more whitespaces and then a `<...>` substring till the end of string
- `|`- or
- `(<br>)` - Group 1: `<br>` tag
- `|` - or
- `<[^>]*>` - `<`, zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `>`.

Comment: Perfect Wictor! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all the tags with the code you already written; then use [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to divide the names and the [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) one to insert the `&` in the desired points.

```js
const myTextParsed = []

let myText = '<div class=\"ExternalClassBE95E28C1751447DB985774141C7FE9C\"><p>Tina Schmelz<br></p><p>Sascha Balke<br></p></div>';

let myTextArray = myText.split('<br>'); 

myTextArray = myTextArray.map(ta => {
  const temp = ta.replaceAll(/<.*?>/gi, '')
  if (temp.length > 0) { myTextParsed.push(temp) }  
});

myText = myTextParsed.join(' & ');

console.log(myText)
```